# Adding JComboBox to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I'm creating a `JTable` in Java & I'm asked to add to the table a `JCheckBox`, `JButton` and a `JComboBox`. The table that I created is displaying all the information, the button is working fine and the `JCheckBox` is also working, the problem I'm facing is that the `JComboBox` is not working. I really can't figure out why. I've tried to look the problem up but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me please?

**The code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class sinX extends JFrame {
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;
private Object[][] data;
private String[] columnNames;
private JButton button;
JComboBox comboBox;
    public sinX() {
    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    setTitle("Programming Languages");
    data = new Object[][]{{"C","Dennis Ritchie",1972,false},{"C++","Bjarne Stroustrup",1983,true},
            {"Python","Guido van Rossum",1991,false},{"Java","James Gosling",1995,true},{
            "JavaScript","Brendan Eich",1995,true},{"C#","Anders Hejlsberg",2001,false},
            {"Scala","Martin Odersky",2003,true}};
    columnNames = new String[] {"Language","Author","Year","Check Box"};
    //model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    //table = new JTable(model);
    //table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] {
            String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class
    };
    //create table model with data
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
        {
            return columnClass[columnIndex];
        }
    };
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    button = new JButton("Remove");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            // check for selected row first
            if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                // remove selected row from the model
                model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected row deleted successfully");
            }
        }
    });
    TableColumn year = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    comboBox.addItem("A");
    comboBox.addItem("B");
    comboBox.addItem("C");
    comboBox.addItem("D");
    year.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new sinX();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> the problem I'm facing is that the JComboBox is not working.

```
year.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

The above code indicates you are trying to use a combo box as an editor for the given column.

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
{
    return false;
}
```

However, you have stated in your model that none of columns are editable.

You need to `return true` for any column where you want to edit the data.

> the JCheckBox is also working

Not really. Yes you see the boolean value is rendered as a check box. However, you can't change its value by clicking on it, unless of course you return true for that column as well.